# Bypass .htaccess when using download_url

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got the following .htaccess file in my a custom directory in Uploads called client.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !(www.)?example.co.uk/client-area*
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [R=403,L]
ErrorDocument 403 'http://www.example.co.uk/client-area/'
```

So if someone tries to access a file in the uploads/client/ directory from anywhere else other than the client-area page, they get redirected.

However, I want to ignore this when I'm using when using the WordPress function `download_url` to access a file in that directory from within functions.php. Is there a rewrite condition I can use to facilitate this?

Comment: @anubhava `download_url(http://www.example.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/client/example.pdf);`

Comment: Is `download_url` a WP function?

Comment: Yes - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/download_url/

Comment: Web server won't know if request is coming due to you calling `download_url` function. You will need to pass some query parameter to help out `mod_rewrite` rules but that is not safe as any visitor of your website can also do the same.

Comment: @anubhava - Ah, thanks. If you want to add that as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you are calling a WP function `download_url` and want to skip this rule from 403.

The thing is that Web server (Apache) won't know if request is coming due to you calling `download_url` function.

As a workaround you will need to pass some query parameter to help out `mod_rewrite` rules but that is not a safe approach as any visitor of your website can also do the same by passing same query paramter.

Answer (score 1):

You can add another `RewriteCond` on the `QUERY_STRING` property.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !(www.)?example.co.uk/client-area*
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^download_url [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [R=403,L]
ErrorDocument 403 'http://www.example.co.uk/client-area/'
```

https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString

**Edit:** I misunderstood the question. I thought you were passing `download_url` in the URL. You could just exclude from your RewriteRule the entire directory where downloadable files are located.

E.g.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !(www.)?example.co.uk/client-area*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/wp-content\/uploads\/((\.[^\.])|([a-z0-9\-_\+\/]))+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [R=403,L]
ErrorDocument 403 'http://www.example.co.uk/client-area/'
```

By the way, I wouldn't really depend on `HTTP_REFERER` to filter content, it can be easily modified/spoofed by the client. The regex in the `RewriteCond` I added, will match letters, numbers, dashes, underscores, pluses and forward slashes. It specifically will not match `".."`. This is to prevent relative URIs from access other files outside of `wp-content/uploads`. (I *think* Apache will actually expand the URI and then try to match the expanded URI against your rules.)

Comment: Hiya, afraid this still doesn't do what I'm after - this allows all documents in that folder to be downloaded; I want to block all files in that folder from being downloaded, *except* when downloaded from that page or via download_url. I'm not sure this can be done, so I'll use a query string for the moment.

Comment: @BFWebAdmin When you use `download_url`, unless otherwise specified, WP copies the file to the temp directory returned by [`get_temp_dir`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_temp_dir/#source-code). If you 'expire' and delete the temp file after a time, and the file name is unique (which it is), you may be better off excluding the temp directory from your `RewriteRule` (replace `wp-content/uploads` in my example).